# Find the count of duplicate property values in an object

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates

```
var db = [
  {Id: "201" , Player: "Nugent",Position: "Defenders"},
  {Id: "202", Player: "Ryan",Position: "Forwards"},
  {Id: "203" ,Player: "Sam",Position: "Forwards"},
  {Id: "204", Player: "Bill",Position: "Midfielder"},
  {Id: "205" ,Player: "Dave",Position: "Forwards"},
];
```

How can I can I find the number of duplicate objects by `Position`.

Notice I have duplicated value as `"Forwards"` (second, third and last object)

I have tried doing:

```
for (var key in db) {
  var value = db[key];
  if ( count of duplicated values == 3) {
    console.log("we have three duplicated values)
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this while the objects are being looped?

Comment: since you have an array of objects, do you need to specify which object property to be duplicated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use another object as a counter, like this

```
var counter = {};
for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i += 1) {
    counter[db[i].Position] = (counter[db[i].Position] || 0) + 1;
}

for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > 1) {
        console.log("we have ", key, " duplicated ", counter[key], " times");
    }
}
```